# Why is LINQ expression "Not Supported" when converting a Char to String inside of it?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

If I make conversion of `firstLetterOfLastName` to string by adding empty string `""` inside of expression I get the following exception when try to convert result to `List`:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Code which gives trouble:

```
 public ActionResult Index(char firstLetterOfLastName = 'A') {
            var queryResult = db.Persons.Where(person => person.LastName.StartsWith(firstLetterOfLastName + ""))
            .OrderBy(person => person.Id);       
            var list = queryResult.ToList(); // EXCEPTION
            return View(list);
        }
```

However, when I make conversion earlier outside of the LINQ expression like here:

```
public ActionResult Index(char firstLetterOfLastName = 'A') {
        string flofnAsString = firstLetterOfLastName + "";
        var queryResult = db.Persons.Where(person => person.LastName.StartsWith(flofnAsString + ""))
        .OrderBy(person => person.Id);
        var list = queryResult.ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
```

there is no problem. Why is so?

Comment: Is there a message in the exception?

Comment: Rather than converting to a string with + "", can you try converting with the .ToString() method? I'd like to know what happens when you use that method inside the LINQ expression

Comment: Additionally, I'd check the type of queryResult when the exception is thrown. From the exception type, it might be that queryResult can't be converted to a list. (Why it can't might be related to the char->string conversion)

Comment: @Vlad274 `ToString` is not supported by EF.

Comment: @Vlad274 It's not that it can't convert the query to a list; it's that it can't build the query at all because it's using methods EF doesn't support, it's simply that the expressions are not inspected and parsed into SQL until the query is evaluated, which is when he calls `ToList`.

Comment: @Servy I missed the EF piece. I read this as a straight C# and LINQ question

Answer (score 5):

The error tells you exactly why.  The query provider doesn't know how to map that operation into SQL.  It does know what to do with the result of that operation when you executed it in your application and evaluated it to its value.

Comment: is it because `firstLetterOfLastName + ""` will be translated into `firstLetterOfLastName.ToString() + ""` and ToString is not supported?

Comment: @Selman22 It's not doing such a transformation at all.  He's applying the `+` operator on an `object` and a `string`.  The query provider doesn't know how to map that operator to SQL.  The C# implementation of that operator is to (after some null checks) call `ToString` on the object and then concat the strings, but a query provider can do whatever it wants instead.

Comment: @user2864740 And there is no overload of the `+` operator for accepting a first argument of type `char`.  The only applicable overload is the one accepting an argument of type `object`, to which `char` is a valid operand for.

Comment: @Servy Ahh. I see. Consider moving relevant comment information into the response itself (which is currently pretty .. lacking in details).

Comment: @user2864740 What is there to say.  The OP already knows exactly what code can't be parsed by the query provider.  He identified what couldn't be parsed, and identified how to fix it.  As to why, it's simply because the query provider wasn't written to support it.  That's pretty much all there is *to* say.  The OP isn't asking what code can't be parsed into SQL; it's very clearly already identified in the question; I see no need to repeat it back at him.

Comment: @Servy The answer feels like a primary comment as it is written. The interesting details are only mentioned in the comments, primarily wrt. the `+` operator. It is not hard to edit answers .. not sure what reason there is to *not* improve them and/or become defensive towards suggestions of such.

Comment: @user2864740 The question itself isn't all that interesting, that's quite right.  It, as a consequence, has an uninteresting answer.  That's still the answer to the question though.  The rest is all just a tangent to the question that you happen to find interesting, despite it being a tangent, belonging in comments.

Comment: Then leave an uninteresting comment to an uninteresting question. Or take the time to turn a reply into something useful. It is not the "No" or "Yes" that are of value, but the reasoning behind such - when such can supported in an objective manner.

Comment: @user2864740 It's an answer to the question that is asked.  That's why it's posted as an answer.  Just because the answer to a question is boring to you doesn't mean it should be in a comment, and just because a tangential comment is more interesting to you doesn't mean it should be in an answer.